# How to get data from youtube api automaticly when you add item on django

Tags: python, django, youtube-api

I have model class in Django such as

```
class YoutubeVideo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=2000, unique=True)
    duration = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to get duration (and some other data) when I add a video_id on admin interface. 
How can I trigger my crawler after adding an item.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the save method of your model:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if self.video_id is not None and self.duration is None:
        self.duration = call_youtube_to_get_duration()
    return super(YoutubeVideo, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This is exactly  what I am looking for Thank you.